# convert JacobiSN to JacobiDN identity

Tags: elliptic-functions

I have a Jacobi Elliptic sn function:
\begin{equation}
0.9258200998{\it sn} \left(  0.7559289460\,It-{\it 
ns} \left( - 1.154700538,- 0.6123724359\,\sqrt {2}
 \right) ,- 0.6123724359\,\sqrt {2} \right) 
\end{equation}
which is equivalent to 
\begin{equation}
0.7559289458\,\sqrt {2}{\it dn} \left(  0.7559289458\,t, 0.5
 \right) 
\end{equation}
Here, 'I' is $\sqrt{-1}$, sn is Jacobi sine function,ns is inverse Jacobi sine function.

I obtained the equivalency by plotting the two functions for different time intervals. But, I am unable to explicitly convert one function to the other. I have searched a lot but I am unable to find an explicit conversion formula. Can someone help me out?